# How to pass radio button value to php page using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, html

I am showing radio button in html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FileUploadForm"  name="FileUpload" ng-submit="submitData(FileUpload)" novalidate>
        <div style="text-align: left;font-size: 20px;padding: 10px;color: #487eaa;">
            <font> Upload Resume</font>
        </div>
        <div class="file-upload">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name"  ng-model="name" />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="text" id="place" name="place"  ng-model="place" />
            <br /><br />
            <label class="control-label" for="Dilation" style="padding:3px 0;">Dilation</label>
            <label>Yes&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="dilation" id="dilation" ng-model="dilation" value="Yes" ng-checked="false" /></label>

            <label>No&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="dilation" id="dilation" ng-model="dilation" value="No" ng-checked="false" /></label>
            <br /><br />

            <label class="control-label" for="NCT" style="padding:3px 0;">NCT</label>
            <label>Right&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="nct" id="nct" ng-model="nct" value="Right" ng-checked="false" /></label>
            <label>Left&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="nct" id="nct" ng-model="nct" value="Left" ng-checked="false" /></label>
            <br /><br />


            <input type="file" id="i_file" name="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" ng-disabled="FileUploadForm.$invalid" />
            <br /><br />
            <div ng-bind="dilation" ng-hide="dilation"></div>
            <div ng-bind="nct" ng-hide="nct"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And here is my angular controller

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $upload) {

$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    $scope.message = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
        var file = $files[i];
        console.log(file);
        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: 'upload.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {name: $scope.name,place: $scope.place, dilation: dilation, nct: nct },            
            file: file
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message = data;                
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.message = data;
        });
    }
};
});
```

And here is my php code(upload.php)

```
$result = array("filename" => $_FILES["file"],"name" => $_POST['name'],"place" => $_POST['place'],"dilation" => $_POST['dilation'],"nct" => $_POST['nct']);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aabyv4kx/
and getting response like this

```
name:qqq,place:eeee,dilation:{\"ng339\":8},nct:{\"ng339\":10}
```

I am new to `angularjs` please help me sort this.

Comment: I don't see a `var dilation` or `dilation = whatever` anywhere in your JS code. I'd say you meant `$scope.dilation` instead?

Comment: Check out dnode. I think it is applicable to your problem.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv $scope.dilation its working. Thanks. But same thing iam   using to checkbox its. Why?